# removing a pending change in an entity 5.0 context?

Tags: c#, linq-to-entities

let say that I have a code something like this;

```
using (DAL.MyContext db = new DAL.MyContext())
{
   foreach (var item in UpdatedValues)
   {
      try
      {
          switch (item.Status)
          {
                case Enums.Status.Delete:
                   //stuff
                   break;
                case Enums.Status.Updated:
                   //stuff
                   break;
                case Enums.Status.Added:
                   //stuff
                   break;
          }

          db.SaveChange(); //crashing here
      }
      catch(Exception ex)
      {
         tools.log(ex);
         /*
              how to remove the last action so the for each can continue?
         */
      }
   }
}
```

I would like to remove the last change from the context.

why?

if there is an exception, the next change will also thrown an exception since the last one didn't work but is still in the "context" so it will try to save again.

is that possible?

Comment: It's a little hard to understand what you want. The foreach will continue to next item in UpdatedValues. Can you post something more?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

unless someone find this not "proper" this seem to fix my issue;

in the catch, after looking at `System.Data.Entity.Internal.InternalEntityEntry.State` version 5.0 with `ILSpy`, all I need is

```
    internal static void UndoContextChange(DB_Context db)
    {
        foreach (var item in db.ChangeTracker.Entries())
        {
            if (item.State == System.Data.EntityState.Modified)
            {
                item.State = System.Data.EntityState.Unchanged;
            }
            else if (item.State == System.Data.EntityState.Deleted)
            {
                item.State = System.Data.EntityState.Unchanged;
                item.CurrentValues.SetValues(item.OriginalValues); //just in case
            }
            else if (item.State == System.Data.EntityState.Added)
            {
                item.State = System.Data.EntityState.Detached;
            }
        }        
    }
```

Comment: @philsoady, my question now would be which one is best detached or unchanged when an error is thrown, detached does remove the object from the Entries list while unchanged keep it there.

Comment: depends on future use of the context content.  A find() will use the still attached content .  Local() will still use attached content.

Comment: @philsoady, Detached create issue if that same record need to be modified again in the same context so Unchanged is the one that need to be used in my case. find more information here; http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.entitystate.aspx

Comment: you cant put it in twice, Thats why I said consider NEW context.

Answer (score 0):

There isnt a Detach method :-(
But the Entity State can bet altered
See the Enum....

```
// Type: System.Data.EntityState
public enum EntityState
{
Detached = 1,
Unchanged = 2,
Added = 4,
Deleted = 8,
Modified = 16,
}

//See
Context.Entry(poco).State = state;
```

Otherwise just Renew the Context.  Often a better approach anyway.